# ion-cards aligned in horizontal order?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, css-position

Is it possible to have the ion-cards aligned next to each other rather than in down to down fashion?

I want the cards in horizontal rather in vertical order.

Comment: many ways to do it. use grid/horizontal scroll...

Comment: Hi Suraj, Thanks for the reply. Could you show an example or a link i can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrap `ion-card` in `ion-row>ion-col`

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-4>
    <ion-card>Hello1</ion-card>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-4>
    <ion-card>Hello2</ion-card>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-4>
    <ion-card>Hello3</ion-card>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Hey Amit, Thanks for the reply. When i am trying ur way , still the cards are coming in vertical (row wise).

Comment: It is coming next to each other ? To the right of every card?

Comment: each cards are placed on same horizontal line that is ion-row. First try the code in answer then replace with your card.

Comment: When i am trying ur code : its showing :                                                           Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Comment: thanks amit , its working.. i got the idea abt it. Have a great day!